# Is there anything near the rune in the water at Lady Boyle's Last Party?

Tags: dishonored

Normally, when there's a collectible in a particular location, it's because the designers want you to visit that location.  For example, Outsider Shrines generally have runes near them.

There is a rune in the river outside Lady Boyle's Last Party.  I thought that there might be a sewer entrance to the party or something that the rune was trying to guide me towards, but I looked and didn't see anything.

**Did I miss anything, or is there really nothing there besides the rune in the water?**

Comment: There is in fact a sewer entrance to the party but it is not near the rune. It is under the bridge and you have to possess a fish to swim through the bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about this one:

[image: map]

(Image from the [Dishonored Maps App for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dishonored-official-map-app/id565975972?mt=8).)

If so, doesn't look like there's anything of note there. I don't recall finding anything interesting.

Comment: Yep, that's the one.